# JQuery Adding elements to a list from parsed JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-mobile

I am trying to parse some JSON and take the elements "startTime" and "endTime" and add them to a list.  I am able to receive the JSON successfully, however I am having trouble properly parsing and then looping through to add each instance to the list.  Inside of the UL, i would like to create lists for each, like i demo below:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'localhost:8080/sample?',
   dataType: 'json',            
success: function (data){ 
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
var $calAppts = $('#appts');      
   $('<li data-role="list-divider">' + this.startTime
   + ' - ' + this.endTime + '<span class="ui-li-count"></span></li>').appendTo($appts);
```

The HTML where I am trying to insert the LI inside of the UL:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="headerDate">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="appts">  

  </ul>
</div>
```

So basically for each appointment i get back in the JSON, I want to add a new LI with the startTime and endTime.

I am using JQM 1.3.2, and JQUERY 1.8.0.

Thank you

Comment: You likely don't have valid data, you've set the dataType to JSON, which means you already have a javascript object, and passing that object to $.parseJSON will likely fail, as you're now parsing it twice.

Comment: Also, inside the ajax success function, what are you expecting `this` to reference ?

Comment: Can you please post the JSON response that you are recieving ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'localhost:8080/sample?',
dataType: 'json',            
success: function (data){ 
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
var $calAppts = $('#appts');      
 $('<li data-role="list-divider">' + this.startTime
 + ' - ' + this.endTime + '<span class="ui-li-count"></span></li>').appendTo($appts);
```

Into this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'localhost:8080/sample?',
    dataType: 'json',            
    success: function (data){ 
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);

    $.each( json, function( key, value ) {

      var agrega = "<li data-role='list-divider'>";
      if(key=='startTime')
      {
          agrega = agrega +  value
      }
      if(key=='endTime')
      {
          agrega = agrega + ' - ' +  value;
      }
       agrega = agrega + '<span class="ui-li-count"></span></li>';
       $('#appts').append(agrega);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample, it seems your problem is that you're trying to look for the `startTime` property in the wrong place (on `this`). In your sample, the `startTime` property should be present on your parsed JSON, so accessing the key there should do the trick:

```
$('<li data-role="list-divider">' + json.startTime
  + ' - ' + json.endTime + '<span class="ui-li-count"></span></li>').appendTo($appts);
```

If the returned JSON is a series of times, then you'll also want to loop through the JSON object as well:

```
$.each(json, function(key, value) {
  if (key === 'startTime') {
    // append to the list
  }
});
```

*Additional note*:

If JSON is what is being returned from the AJAX call, then you shouldn't need to use `$.parseJSON` on it. JSON objects are JavaScript objects, so you can simply use the returned value and access they keys on it (meaning you can use `data.startTime` directly instead of parsing it first).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the response below

```
var ulObject = $("#appts");

var ajaxObject = $.ajax({
type:"POST",
dataType:"json",
url:"" //Provide the URL in the field to be processed.
});

ajaxObject.done(function(msg){
var jsonResponse = $.parseJSON(msg);
var listObjectStart = '<li data-role="list-divider">'
var listObjectEnd = '</li>';
$.each(jsonResponse,function(key,value){
if(key === "startTime")
{
listObjectStart += value;
}
else if(key === "endTime")
{
listObjectStart += '-'+value+'<span class="ui-li-count"></span>';
}
});

listObjectStart += listObjectEnd;

ulObject.append(listObjectStart);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if server send the data back to client in json format.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'localhost:8080/sample?',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $("#appts").append('<li data-role="list-divider">' + data.startTime 
+ ' - ' + data.endTime + '<span class="ui-li-count"></span></li>');
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('There was an error in communication.');
    }
});
```